# TS syntax errors on ng build but not in the IDE (not --prod)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a static function which takes in a key name as a string and returns a lambda which checks if that field contains another string. So far what I have is this (somewhat messy) code:

```
type Only<T, K> = {
    [P in keyof T as (T[P] extends K ? P : never)]: T[P]
};

export class Functions {
    public static stringIncludesMatcherForKey<T>(key: keyof Only<T, string>): (a: T, b: string) => boolean {
        const stringifier = (obj: T) => (obj[key as unknown as keyof T] as unknown as string).toLowerCase() || '';
        return (obj: T, text: string) => stringifier(obj).includes(text);
    }
}
```

This function will only accept key names which have a type of string. For example, if you use it with the following interface:

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    birthDate: Date;
}

class CheckPeople 
{
    Foo() {
        const firstNameMatcher = Functions.stringIncludesMatcherForKey<Person>('firstName'); // Fine
        const birthDateMatcher = Functions.stringIncludesMatcherForKey<Person>('birthDate'); // Error
    }
}
```

In short, the function will only accept 'firstName' or 'lastName' as keys and anything else shows an error in my IDE as expected.

However, when I run ng build it outputs a bunch of confusing syntax errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/_common/pipeline/Functions.ts:30:19 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

30     [P in keyof T as (T[P] extends K ? P : never)]: T[P]
                     ~~
src/app/_common/pipeline/Functions.ts:30:28 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

30     [P in keyof T as (T[P] extends K ? P : never)]: T[P]
                              ~~~~~~~
src/app/_common/pipeline/Functions.ts:30:50 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

30     [P in keyof T as (T[P] extends K ? P : never)]: T[P]
                                                    ~
src/app/_common/pipeline/Functions.ts:30:51 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

30     [P in keyof T as (T[P] extends K ? P : never)]: T[P]
                                                     ~
src/app/_common/pipeline/Functions.ts:31:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

31 };
```

I have created the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jej854?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts) which shows that the example compiles fine and runs as expected.

This implies that the error is coming from a difference in build configurations, but I have no idea what to look for in there.

Comment: Errors like this more look like a circulair dependency in typescript. It wont throw a real ts error, but weird errors like this.

Comment: @Robert-JanKuyper I see, what could be the source of difference between how StackBlitz is handling it and my development environment? I'm not sure which part of my configuration would be helpful to post.